# Dynamic python/flask route function naming

Tags: python, flask

first off, a disclaimer: I'm not well versed in python or flask, so bear with me.

I'm trying to put together a minimal API using flask, i was planning to dynamically generate routes and their associated procs from the contents of a subdirectory.
The code looks something like this:

```
from flask import Flask
import os
app = Flask(__name__)
configs = os.getcwd() + "/configs"
for i in os.listdir(configs):
    if i.endswith(".json"):
        call = "/" + os.path.splitext(i)[0]
        @app.route(call, methods=['POST'])
        def call():
            return jsonify({"status": call + "Success"}), 200
```

The plan being to iterate over a bunch of config files and use their naes to define the routes. Now, this works for a single config file, but wont work for multiple files as I end up trying to overwrite the function `call` that is used by each route.

I can factor out most of the code to a separate function as long as i can pass in the call name. However it seems that however i go about this i need to dynamically name the function generated and mapped to the route.

So, my question is: how can use the contents of a variable, such as 'call' to be the function name?

i.e. something like

```
call = "getinfo"
def call():  # Effectively being evaled as def getinfo():
```

Everything i've tried hasn't worked, and i'm not confident enough in my python syntax to know if it's because i'm just doing something silly.

Alternatively is there another way to do what i'm trying to achieve?

Thanks for all and any feedback!

Comment: Please, describe your use case in more detail, it sounds you like to serve static files?

Comment: You can use a variable in your path. `@app.route('/configs/<filename>')` and then `def handler(filename):`.

Comment: @rebelling, the use case isn't to serve static files, its actually to validate json per req against each config file and then call another script with the relevant arguments. This isn't a proper application, just a way to expose a particular API interface via http for development usage (it's not normally accessible).

Comment: @BBrown thanks for the feedback, I'm not sure how i'd do that, without still needing to iterate over the `@app.route` call?

Comment: Are you trying to create one handler for each of many files? Just create one handler. Use the path in the requested URL as a variable inside your handler.

Comment: I am currently trying to create a handler for each file, although am in no way tied to that. atm i can't figure out how to bind multiple routes to the same handler (at least looping the way that i am currently).

Comment: But don't! Create one route with one handler and pass the config name as a variable, as BBrown is telling you.

Comment: Hi Folks, thanks for the help. I've done as suggested and just have the one route and handler now. And all is well, and things are working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help. I've moved to one route and one handler and building up the file list, and handling of the request paths, etc separately.
This is a sanitized version of the model i now have:

```
from flask import Flask
import os
calls = []
cfgs = {}
app = Flask(__name__)
configs = os.getcwd() + "/configs"
for i in os.listdir(configs):
    if i.endswith(".json"):
        cfgs[call] = os.path.splitext(i)[0]
        calls.extend([call])

@app.route('/<call>', methods=['POST'])
    def do(call):
        if call not in calls:
            abort(400, "invalid call")
        # Do stuff
        return jsonify({"status": call + "Success"}), 200

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

So, thanks to the above comments this is doing what i'm after. Still curious to know if there is any way to use variables in function names?